# Отправка части выбранных изображений на сервер через форму

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, файлы, fileupload

Нужно реализовать загрузку изображений, их предварительный просмотр, удаление выбранных и отправку на сервер. Также нужно предусмотреть, чтобы можно было в любой момент отправить эти изображения.

Для загрузки использую следующий инпут:

```
 <input type="file" name="images[]" accept="image/*" multiple>
```

Поскольку загруженные фалй лежат в `FileList`, который `readonly`, я сохраняю вновь выбранные валидные изображения в отдельный массив `var images = []`. С превью изображений на странице все понятно. Соответственно, когда пользователь удаляет из интерфейса картинку, то скрипт удялет её из моего `images`.

Но как мне отправить на сервер эти самые изображения из сформированного массива при нажатии на кнопку `submit` не используя ajax? Я пробовал сделать так:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    $('input[type=file]').val(images);
});
```

Но такой способ не сработал. Так как отправить результирующий массив файлов через форму?

Answer (score 0):

Для отправки изображений можно использовать `XMLHttpRequest` с `FormData` ([пример](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects))

Comment: Я же написал: *не используя Ajax*

Comment: Думаю, что иначе никак

Comment: спасибо! Мои сомнения подтвердились